# Reactjs: can I safely access a sibling component using state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ReactJS since just a week or two and I'm now trying to build an App using it.

I think I understood how I should make a Child Component communicates with its Parent Component passing a function as a prop.
But now I'd like to do something different and make 2 sibling Components communicate with each other.
I know I could achieve this using their common Parent Component, but I'd really love to declare some methods on one of those sibling Components and reuse them all over the App.

**So here is my idea and my question:** can I safely set the state of a Parent Component putting there the "this" from Child Component and then use this variable on other Components?

I already wrote this code and it's working, but I don't understand if this is a good approach or a bad one.

Here some parts of my code to let you see what I'm doing.

Parent Component:

```
class App extends Component{
  state = {}
  render(){
    return <Router>
      <div id="page">
        <Header app={this} />
        <div id="main" class="row">
          <Sidebar app={this} />
          <Content app={this} />
        </div>
        <Footer app={this} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  }
}
```

Sidebar:

```
class Sidebar extends Component{
  state = {menu: []}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.app.setState({sidebar: this})
  }

  populateSidebar = (sidebar) => {
    this.setState({menu: sidebar})
  }

  render(){
    if (this.state.menu.length == 0){
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <sidebar class="col-3">
        <ul>
            {this.state.menu.map(item => <li><Link to={item.url}>{item.text}</Link></li>)}
        </ul>
      </sidebar>
    )
  }
}
```

User Component (it's a Child of the Content Component. The Content Component just does some routing based on the url):

```
class User extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.app.state.sidebar
    this.props.app.state.sidebar.populateSidebar(
      [
        {
          url: "/user/add",
          text: "Add new user"
        },
        {
          url: "/user/list",
          text: "Users list"
        }
      ]
    )
  }

  async componentWillUnmount() {
    await this.props.app.state.sidebar
    this.props.app.state.sidebar.populateSidebar([])
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserAdd />
        <UserList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I know that what I'm accomplishing here is so basic that I could totally do it in a different way, for example putting the sidebar menu as an array on the Parent Component's state. But let's say that I want a bunch of methods on Sidebar and let all my other components using them without rewriting too much code. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: > declare some methods on one of those sibling Components and reuse them all over the App.

What methods are you trying to reuse?
Why not make a `helpers.js` file which can be called from anywhere with this common method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd really love to declare some methods on one of those sibling
>   Components and reuse them all over the App.

A better approach is to create a helper class with some static methods and use it everywhere across your components, this class even doesn't have to be a react component just a regular ES6 class, for example:

```
class MyHelper {
    static doSummation(num1, num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    static doMultiplication(num1, num2) {
        return num1 * num2
    }

    // ... other helper methods as you want
}

export default MyHelper;
```

Then in your React components you can import it and use its helper methods:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MyHelper from './MyHelper';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {MyHelper.doSummation(1, 2)};
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You can even, for better organization, have as many helper classes as you want, for example `MathHelper`, `StringFormattingHelper`, etc...

Comment: Thanks! I can't think of anything I couldn't accomplish just doing it as you said. So, I'll rewrite the code as you suggested